# Форматирование строк в css и прирост производительности - миф или реальность?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, производительность

Верстаю проект, причём он будет высоконагруженным, выжимается буквально всё в том числе и из шаблона сайта. Так вот, вопрос, озвученный в заголовке, актуален и востребован как возможность немного ускорить сайт на стороне клиента, или толком отдачи никакой и эти телодвижения - понапрасну?
Сам файл стилей впрочем не сильно масштабен - около 2000 строк.

Comment: Писал вспешке с затуманенным разумом, точнее было бы так - влияет ли количество строк.

Answer (score 4):

На минимизации .css только за счет whitespace вы выиграете капельку трафика и практически ничего в скорости что рендера на клиенте, что выдачи на сервере (на сервере даже потеряете).

Сделать это стоит только потому, что сделать это очень просто.

Есть множество гораздо более полезных направлений. Про клиентскую оптимизацию рекомендую отличное могучее книго: «[Реактивные веб-сайты](http://speedupyourwebsite.ru/books/reactive-websites/)».

Answer (score 1):

При написании цсс главная оптимизация заключается в написание нормальных селекторов. Вот можно почитать статью про [эксперемент с цсс селекторами](http://webo.in/articles/habrahabr/19-css-efficiency-tests/), там две части. Хоть результаты и методика измерения скорости довольно спорны, но выводы там сделаны правильные. Но а если серьезно, то оптимизация цсс не принесет каких-то существенных улучшений, правда и сделать ее можно довольно быстро. Лучше уделите повешенное внимание оптимизации javascript, особенно если используете sizzle для поиска элементов, вот там есть где разойтись...